# How to display solution?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to create a program that displays a solution to a problem and I need a way to display the solution that it created. I have two operations that can be used to solve the problem though and the order in which they are called matters.

```
test(a) :- write('use a ').
test(b) :- write('use b '), fail.

test(c) :- test(a), test(b), test(a).
test(c) :- test(a), test(a).
```

Please note this is an example and should not be taken literally. Think of test(a) and test(b) as the operations and test(c) as the function that's checking which order would be valid.

Now `test(c).` will print even the ones that fails. Resulting in output "use a use b use a use a".

Comment: Show a little code maybe?

Comment: The most elegant way is to let the Prolog toplevel display the solution. Define a predicate `solution(S)` which is true if `S` is a solution. When you then query `?- solution(S).`, the toplevel will display the solution for you.

Comment: Write won't work ... in order to print the message it would have to be before it tests the next step, resulting in the message being printed even if it doesn't work, otherwies it'll be backwards.

Comment: Taking a page from the "test-driven development" playbook, when I am writing Prolog code to search for a solution that is too complex to display well by `write/1`, I make a practice of writing a predicate that will "pretty print" that structure.  Of course this fits the TDD mold well because I can test that predicate, using a hard-coded "solution", before I write the first lick of code that is going to implement the search.  That said, I can't make sense of your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems a legitimate call for assertz/retract.

These builtins allow to track the chronological sequence, and to store arbitrary Prolog terms, then you could write

```
:- dynamic results/2.

test(a) :- a_code(Result), assertz(results(a, Result)).
test(b) :- b_code(Result), assertz(results(b, Result)).

test(c) :- test(a), test(b), test(a).
test(c) :- test(a), test(a).

check_results :- forall(retract(Name, Result), writeln(Name = Result)).
```

If you want to track failed executions, you can extend that schema:

```
test(a) :- a_code(Result) -> assertz(results(ok(a), Result)) ; assertz(results(ko(a), _)).
test(b) :- b_code(Result) -> assertz(results(ok(b), Result)) ; assertz(results(ko(b), _)).
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using side effects, consider using a DCG that describes the list of goals. Your example can be easily turned into a DCG with a few mechanical rewriting steps, for example:

```
test(a) --> ['use a'].
test(b) --> ['use b'], { false }.

test(c) --> test(a), test(b), test(a).
test(c) --> test(a), test(a).
```

Then you can query:

```
?- phrase(test(c), Ls).
Ls = ['use a', 'use a'].
```

When you have such a list `Ls`, you can easily write it in any way you want. Notice though that the toplevel already prints each solution in a useful way, and there may be little reason to do so yourself.

Comment: This looks pretty interesting I'll give it a try. Though could you clarify some syntactic differences ? As why you are using --> ? What does that do exactly ?

Comment: (-->)/2 defines a DCG rule. Read about DCGs ("definite clause grammars") in any good Prolog book. In brief: A DCG always describes a list. In DCGs, you can read (,)/2 as "and then". [T] stands for a terminal, {Goal} for a regular Prolog goal, and NT for a DCG nonterminal. When describing a list, and it seems complicated to describe it, always consider using a DCG. It will typically become much easier with DCGs.